# Carbon en Laravel actualiza registro equivocado

Tags: laravel

Tengo un problema en el controlador con el UPDATE, mi STORE es el siguiente:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $date = Carbon::now('America/Asuncion')->toDateTimeString();
    $cabcaja = new cab_caja($request->all());
    $cabcaja->fecha_inicio = $date;
    $cabcaja->estado = 1;
    $cabcaja->save();
    Flash::success("Caja abierta en fecha");
    return redirect()->route('caja_actual.index');
}
```

Ahí guarda todo perfecto. Pero al actualizar la bd mediante el UPDATE:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $datefin = Carbon::now('America/Asuncion')->toDateTimeString();
    $cabb_caja = cab_caja::find($id);
    $cabb_caja->fecha_fin = $datefin;
    $cabb_caja->estado = 0;
    $cabb_caja->fill($request->all());
    $cabb_caja->save();
    Flash::warning('La caja ha sido cerrada.');
    return redirect()->route('index');
}
```

Me actualiza el campo "fecha_inicio" a la fecha actual (la misma que fecha_fin). Estoy usando Laravel en su versión 5.1

dd($request->all()) :

```
array:6 [▼ "_method" => "PUT" "_token" => "TgjPpopkNFjD8vxbwc1gVZo6wTSa1nI36ZqmsNsR" "gs_cierre" => "9443" "pe_cierre" => "3967" "gs_arreglo" => "100" "pe_arreglo" => "399" ] –
```

Array attributes antes del save() :

```
#attributes: array:12 [▼
"id" => 15
"fecha_inicio" => "2016-07-29 00:37:43"
"fecha_fin" => "2016-07-29 00:43:13"
"gs_apertura" => 5999.0
"pe_apertura" => 3334.0
"gs_cierre" => "9443"
"pe_cierre" => "3967"
"estado" => 0
"gs_arreglo" => "0"
"pe_arreglo" => "0"
"created_at" => "2016-07-29 04:37:43"
"updated_at" => "2016-07-29 04:37:43"
]
```

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrarnos un `dd($request->all());` en el método update?

Comment: array:6 [▼
  "_method" => "PUT"
  "_token" => "TgjPpopkNFjD8vxbwc1gVZo6wTSa1nI36ZqmsNsR"
  "gs_cierre" => "9443"
  "pe_cierre" => "3967"
  "gs_arreglo" => "100"
  "pe_arreglo" => "399"
]

Comment: Ahora sería interesante ver el array de "attributes" al hacer `dd($cabb_caja);` justo antes de llamar el método save del modelo.

Comment: Ahi actualicé el post. Antes del _save()_ sigue correcta la información en _fecha_inicio_ . Luego de pasar por el _save()_ ésta se actualiza a la misma fecha de _fecha_fin_

Comment: ¿Qué versión "exacta" de Laravel es? 5.1.xx ?

Comment: Ahora a reconsultar la versión me rectifico, no es 5.1, exactamente es la 5.2.39

Comment: En este punto no sabría que decirte, aparte de poner información temporal de debug en el método `performUpdate()` de Illuminate\Eloquent\Model o de revisar si algún paquete hace un override o extensión del método `save()`, o en un caso bastante raro que haya problemas con OpCache o similares (realmente no creo).

Comment: Ahora hallé una solución algo informal, actualizo en el final del post lo que hice.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que hice fue realizar un "puente" al save(). Guardé en una variable auxiliar la fecha_inicio, en el primer save() actualiza el campo fecha_inicio de vuelta pero inmediatamente creo una segunda instancia de cab::caja con el único fin de pasarle ésta variable auxiliar a fecha_inicio y actualizarle una vez más. Anexo como quedó finalmente mi UPDATE:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $datefin = Carbon::now('America/Asuncion')->toDateTimeString();
    $cabb_caja = cab_caja::find($id);
    $fechain = $cabb_caja->fecha_inicio;
    $cabb_caja->fecha_fin = $datefin;
    $cabb_caja->estado = 0;
    $cabb_caja->fill($request->all());
    $cabb_caja->save();
    $cabb_caja2 = cab_caja::find($id);
    $cabb_caja2->fecha_inicio = $fechain;
    $cabb_caja2->save();
    Flash::warning('La caja ha sido cerrada.');
    return redirect()->route('index');
}
```

Con ésto quedó solucionado, aunque me quedó la intriga del porqué en el primer *save()* me actualiza el campo *fechainicio*

Comment: Bastante curioso, no debería ser así, voy a hacer una prueba con código similar al tuyo a ver que ocurre.

Comment: Es muy extraño. Creo que el _Carbon_ no le digiere del todo el _save()_

Comment: Acabo de hacer una prueba con un escenario muy similar al tuyo (al de la pregunta) y me funciona perfectamente, lo probé con y sin model binding en la ruta, todo sin problema, lo probé en una instalación nueva de Laravel 5.2.41 sobre Homestead 0.5.0, utilizando Postgres y los campos de fecha son 'timestamp' en la base de datos.

Comment: Quizás pueda ser el motor de base de datos, yo uso MySQL, los campos de fechas también son "timestamp". O también podría ser el local server, yo corro con apache.

Comment: Te cuento que hice el cambio de base de datos a MySQL y funcionó perfectamente también. A apache si no pienso retroceder, ya estoy acostumbrado a las maravillas de NGINX :)

Comment: probaste con cambiar el fill de lugar?? no estaria pisando los datos? probaste hacerlo sin el fill? estoy haciendo algo similar en 5.3 y todo bien